# Possible security feature that disables automation?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am making a Python script with the Selenium Chrome Webdriver to automate this website: https://nordicwellness.se/logga-in/?redirecturl=/mina-sidor/ (it's a Swedish website).

I am trying to automate the login process but I keep getting errors such as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

and

```
Keyboard not reachable
```

I am using the following code to locate the email input field and password input field:

```
emailInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="UserName"]').send_keys('test')
passwordInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('123')
```

I've tried passing multiple `options` and even used the `WebDriverWait` function, even tried Firefox and Safari, but nothing seems to work.

Is it possible that the website has some kind of security feature that doesn't allow automated scripts? If so, is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using not unique locators. There are 3 elements matching `//*[@id="UserName"]` and `//*[@id="Password"]` locators.
Locators should be always unique. In this case you need to take in account the unique parent element to make locators unique.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://nordicwellness.se/logga-in/?redirecturl=/mina-sidor/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//main//input[@id='UserName']"))).send_keys('test')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//main//input[@id='Password']"))).send_keys('123')
```

The result screenshot is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to your XPath. If you inspect the web elements in the page itself, there are actually 3 elements matched the XPath you entered `//*[@id="UserName"]`. Without specifying, Selenium will always match the first return element. Which is hidden in the top menu. This is why you get the error of element not interactable.

A quick solution is to use the direct full XPath as per below :

```
emailInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/form/input[1]').send_keys('test')
passwordInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/form/input[2]').send_keys('123')
```

Or you need to specifically filter out which `//*[@id="UserName"]` you trying to access, for an example :

```
emailInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//main//*[@id="UserName"]').send_keys('test')
passwordInp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//main//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('123')
```